# Using C++ Streams to read Fortran record formatted files

Tags: file-io, stream

I am looking for a way to mirror fortran `read(*,*)` functionality in C++ whilst reading fortran formatted files. I am familiar with, and would like to use a stream like syntax but I am not sure how to write my own/utilise a stream to do what I need. I have files with lines such as:

```
'Version' '5.3'
'This set has 1 member'
'Variable','nlo','EvolCode'
'list',1,1
1.E-05,1.,1.25,10000000.
0.00949 0.00208 -8.77372 0.89445 0.00000 0.00000 0.43318 0.89446
```

As you can see I have to deal with different delimiters (newline, space and comma) as well as making sure that when reading in strings it respects the inverted commas as well as "forgets them" (i.e. they don't end up as part of the resulting string).

In fortran you would write something like:

```
read(*,*) dummyString, versionString
read(*,*) descriptoinString
read(*,*) type, order, code
read(*,*) listType, number, repeats
read(*,*) double1, double2, double3, double4
read(*,*) a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8
```

Whereas the resulting C++ would be like:

```
stream >> dummyString >> versionString;
stream >> descriptoinString
stream >> type >> order >> code
stream >> listType >> number >> repeats
stream >> double1 >> double2 >> double3 >> double4
stream >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >> a5 >> a6 >> a7 >> a8
```

From my basic tests with stringstream, it can't accept multiple delimiters and keeps the inverted commas.

What is the best course of action?

Comment: Seems like streams in C++ are good for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by actually leveraging Fortran. It made sense as Fortran can read the file with relative ease (and in a stream like manner), and this got rid of the big issue of being able to read strings encapsulated in inverted commas. To provide a fuller wrapper I also read in the file using fortran file units.

For a full implementation see [here](https://github.com/VolatileStorm/FortranFileStream)